# Android launch package programmatically

Tags: android

I got list of packaged from tablet(Samsung galaxy tab 2). I am trying to launch them using this. "url" being package name like com.sec.android.app.camera

`PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(url);
startActivity(intent);`

It's working for certain packages only. Camera, browser works but digital clock and whole lot doesn't launch. why ?

MY GOAL IS TO LAUNCH "TASK MANAGER" OR "ACTIVE TASKS". IS THIS POSSIBLE? ALSO I AM NOT ABLE TO FIND PACKAGE NAME FOR THAT.

THANKS,

Comment: what do you mean by active tasks ?? are you planning to re-launch the launched apps ??

Comment: I want to switch among the apps. I am developing this for lock down tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following bit to launch all the apps installed on my device one after another. Some of the apps on android have the same package name and do not return the [meta](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_META_DATA) information unless you request it.

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed applications.
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
                    .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
          for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
              Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);

             if(LaunchIntent != null) {
               startActivity( LaunchIntent );
             }
          }
  }
```

[Here's](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/138412-android-20-list-of-running-applications/) a way to get list of running apps :

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Comment: Good. One step closer. Found the package name.          PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(com.sec.android.app.controlpanel);
startActivity(intent);  This is returning null pointer. Here do I need to ask for meta?

Comment: **Note: [List<RunningAppProcessInfo>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces.**

Comment: Got it. My requirement is to launch that app on a lockdown tablet.

Comment: are you adding any category to the intent ??

Comment: Just tried intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); No luck :(

Comment: The current implementation will look FIRST for a main activity in the category **Android.Content.Intent.CategoryInfo**, next for a main activity in the category **Android.Content.Intent.CategoryLauncher**, or return null if neither are found